# Python Pandas Period Date difference is in * MonthEnds>, NaT, how to convert it into INT value

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert difference between two periods (having NaT values as well) into INT values.
Getting error as: AttributeError: 'NatType' object has no attribute 'n'.

```
import pandas as pd
date_start = pd.Period('10/2018',freq='M')
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                  'date_end': ['2017-01', None , '2019-04','2018-06', 
                               '2018-12', '2019-10']})
df['date_end'] = pd.PeriodIndex(pd.to_datetime(df['date_end'], format='%Y-%m'),
                                freq='M')

df['diff'] = date_start - df['date_end']
df['diff'].apply(lambda x: x.n)
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you have a `None` value in the DataFrame. Try changing that `None` to another date.